# How to change Cordova WKWEBVIEW Engine background colour?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, wkwebview

How to change Cordova WKWEBVIEW Engine "cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" - https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps someone,

In the plugins folder after install. "/projectname/plugins/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine/src/ios/". Inside file "CDVWKWebViewEngine.m" after line: 276 add these two lines of code to change the background to black.

or get the updated fork here:
https://github.com/sputn1k/cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine

code:

```
wkWebView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.11, green:0.13, blue:0.19, alpha:1);

wkWebView.scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.11, green:0.13, blue:0.19, alpha:1);
```